# I cannot run my cpp file to connect mysql in my raspberry pi card

Tags: c++

i have a project in Netbeans to connect to Mysql which is in my Raspberry pi card. so the example code i found is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<mysql/mysql.h> 

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="comment">
using namespace std; // </editor-fold>


MYSQL *connection, mysql;
MYSQL_RES *result;
MYSQL_ROW row;
int query_state;

#define HOST "myhost" //  
#define USER "mysuer" // 
#define PASSWD "mypwd" // 
#define DB "mydb"

int main()
{
//initialize database connection
    mysql_init(&mysql);

// the three zeros are: Which port to connect to, which socket to connect to 
// and what client flags to use.  unless you're changing the defaults you only need to put 0 here
    connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,HOST,USER,PASSWD,DB,0,0,0); 
// Report error if failed to connect to database
    if (connection == NULL) {
        cout << mysql_error(&mysql) << endl;
        return 1;
    }
//Send query to database
        query_state = mysql_query(connection, "select * from settings");
// store result
        result = mysql_store_result(connection);
       while ( ( row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL ) {
// Print result, it prints row[column_number])
        cout << row[0] << "\t" << row[1] << endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

when i run this code i have this error:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/NetBeansProjects/Test1'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/test1
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/NetBeansProjects/Test1'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/test1 build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Test1.o -lbcm2835 `mysql_config --cflags` `mysql_config --libs`
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbcm2835
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:62: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/test1' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/test1] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/NetBeansProjects/Test1'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/NetBeansProjects/Test1'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 3s)
```

Can you help me, thank you

Comment: You seem to be building against a Linux-x86 target. This will not work on a raspberry Pi, where the architecture is armv6 (or armv7 if you have an RPI2). The actual fail seems to be on linking a library called "bcm2835" which cannot be found by the linker.

Comment: @PhilB It is odd the directory path includes that (`GNU-Linux-x86`), although if it's being built on the pi it's being built with an ARM compiler, and unless there's asm in there somewhere it will be fine.  `libbcm2835` is actually a pi-specific library (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbcm2835`

You need to install this library (libbcm2835), which is used to access the GPIO pins on Raspberry Pi A/B/+ models; the current version should also work on the Pi 2 (technically, a bcm2836).

You do not refer to needing the GPIOs, just MySQL, so if you were unaware the example project does this, now you are.

[Documentation for **libbcm2835** is here](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/), and there is a link to the source download at the top (4th paragraph).  As far as I am aware, it is not available as a binary package anywhere.

If you are new to installing libraries from source, after you run `sudo make install`, be sure to run `sudo ldconfig` so the linker can find the library.

Comment: Hi thank you for answers, i downloaded the bcm2835 library but i don't know how to remove the GNU linux x 86 and change it to ARM of raspberry pi

Comment: Don't worry about it.  I would guess someone left that in there (or used it in the first place) by mistake; it's just a directory path in the source package.  It is extremely unlikely there's any actual [assembler code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) in such a relatively high level project.  C and C++ themselves are completely portable.  If you are using the compiler on the pi, it will be compiled for the pi.  Since libbcm2835 is being used, it is a safe bet it's been tested for that purpose too.

Comment: For bcm2835 it's ok but my code still got error for every line of my code for example for the sixth line i have this : Unable to resolve identifier MYSQL_RES.

Comment: Maybe you should look for a better example to learn from?  Keep in mind it doesn't have to be written for the raspberry pi -- anything [POSIX compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) will work on Raspbian and the other GNU/Linux pi distros.   Which is to say, pretty much anything that doesn't also clearly involve MS Windows.  Looks like MySQL has [an official C++ API with documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/).   There's literally 1000+ questions about it on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%5Bmysql%5D+is%3Aquestion) as well...

Comment: ...If you restrict yourself to searches and material that reference the Raspberry Pi when you don't have to, you are kind of tying both hands behind your back.   C++ is C++.  MySQL is MySQL.  They are the same whether you're developing on a pi, your laptop, etc.  The only platform specific details will be little things that aren't standardized in C++ (which isn't much  in this context), and those things will be the same across linux, at least, which has been around a pretty long time.

Comment: i resolved this problem by encoding the cpp file inUTF-8 without BOM, all errors disappeared